# CUDA issue in a simple program

Tags: c, cuda

I've spent so much time trying to find out what is going on? The problem is that I'm not able to invoke this simple kernel from my host code. I'm sure that the error will be notable immediately for some people but I feel I'm wasting a lot of time without reason probably. So I'd really appreciate any help.

This is my .cpp code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shrUtils.h>
#include <cutil_inline.h>
#include <cutil_gl_inline.h>
#include <cuda.h>


CUfunction reduce0;    //i've used many ways to declare my kernel function,but.....


int main( int argc , char *argv[] ){

    int i,N,sum;
    int *data;
    int *Md;
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    N=(int)pow((float)2,(float)atoi(argv[1]));
    data=(int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));

    for (i=0;i<N;i++){
        data[i]=rand() % 10 + 1;    
    }
    cudaMalloc((void**) &Md, N );

    clock_t start = clock();

    dim3 dimBlock(512,0);
    dim3 dimGrid(1,1);

    reduce0<<< dimGrid,dimBlock >>>(Md,Md);    



    sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        sum=sum+data[i];
    } 

    printf("Sum of the %d-array is %d \n", N , sum);  
    printf("Time elapsed: %f\n", ((double)clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);   

return 0;

}
```

and here is my .cu code

```
 __global__ void reduce0(int*g_idata, int*g_odata){

extern __shared__ int sdata[];

// each thread loadsone element from global to shared mem

unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
unsigned int i= blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+ threadIdx.x;
sdata[tid] = g_idata[i];

__syncthreads();

// do reduction in shared mem

for(unsigned int s=1; s < blockDim.x; s *= 2) {
if(tid % (2*s) == 0){
sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];
}

__syncthreads();
}

// write result for this block to global mem
if(tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}
```

So I ask what should I do to invoke the kernel? On compile it doesn't recognise this symbol "<<<" and as far as reduce0() it recognises it only if I declare in .cpp! Please someone help me to finally start with real cuda things!

Comment: How are you invoking the compiler?

Answer (score 1):

CUfunction is a driver API abstraction - not needed if you are going to use the language integration feature that enables the <<<>>> syntax of a kernel invocation.

If you don't have to use the driver API (and most people don't), just move your C++ code into the .cu file and invoke the kernel much as you are doing now.

The `cudaMalloc()` call allocates device memory that the CPU cannot read or write.  You have to copy the input for the reduction into your device memory using `cudaMemcpy(...,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);` then, after you are done processing, copy the output to host memory using `cudaMemcpy(..., cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);`

ps That reduction kernel is very slow.  I would recommend you open the reduction SDK and use one of the kernels from there.

Alternatively, use the Thrust library that will be included in CUDA 4.0.  Thrust supports very fast and flexible reductions.

Comment: thanks for your response.
if i move my cpp file to cu file how will it be clear which is the host code and which is the device code?i mean that as far as i know cpp=host code and cu=device code.
Furthermore can you give me a tutorial (a link to a tutorial or something like that) how a kernel can be invoked by the host code?

Comment: ps Im aware of the 7 steps of improvement for this algorithm.What im doing right now is part of my thesis

Comment: Another thing.No i dont want to use the cufunction.It was the last thing i tried to make this thing work!So i just forgot to clear it ;)

Comment: nvcc supports keywords that you can use to tell the compiler which functions are intended for the host versus device.  __device__ functions can only execute on the device.  (Some of the reduction samples use these as subroutines to operate on shared memory.)  __global__ functions execute on the device, but can be configured and launched from host code.  The __host__ keyword specifically denotes functions intended only for the host.  You can mark functions with multiple keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Your code invoking the kernel must be processed by the NVCC compiler. ( <<< is not valid C++) Typically than means putting it in the .cu file. You do not want to move all you cpp code into cu (as you asked in a comment), just the code invoking the kernel.

Change

```
CUfunction reduce0;
```

to

```
void reduce_kernel(int*g_idata, int*g_odata);
```

and replace these lines:

```
dim3 dimBlock(512,0);
dim3 dimGrid(1,1);

reduce0<<< dimGrid,dimBlock >>>(Md,Md);
```

with:

```
reduce_kernel(Md, Md);
```

and add this to your .cu file:

```
void reduce_kernel(int*g_idata, int*g_odata)
{
    dim3 dimBlock(512,0);
    dim3 dimGrid(1,1);

    reduce0<<< dimGrid,dimBlock >>>(g_idata, g_odata);  
}
```

This off the top of my head, so might be slightly off, but you can get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your code invoking the kernel must be processed by the NVCC compiler. ( <<< is not valid C++) Typically than means putting it in the .cu file. You do not want to move all you cpp code into cu (as you asked in a comment), just the code invoking the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, I think I found an error in your cudaMalloc call. Even if this isn't an actual error I think it's better programming practice for portability. It should instead be:

```
cudaMalloc((void**) &Md, sizeof(int)*N);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Windows machine, check the article for setting up Visual Studio 2010 for CUDA 3.2:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/186655/CUDA-3-2-on-VS2010-in-9-steps.aspx